# Is SD card definitely defect if badblocks reports bad blocks?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card

After my Raspberry PI had sporadic boot problems, I gave the MicroSD card a (data-destructive) stress test.

If [`badblocks`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96774/stress-testing-sd-cards-using-linux) reports bad blocks on the card, is it definitely bad? In the sense that a healthy card should not produce any errors in this test.

(I'm not asking "is the card definitely good if `badblocks` finds nothing")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is ripe for the garbage bin.

A flash based medium should normally never give errors while using `badblocks` to the OS/application.
If it does it means that:

1. It is worn out to the point the wear-leveling doesn't have enough room anymore.
2. (part of) the flash memory itself is faulty.
3. The controller chip is bad.
4. Any combination of the above can also occur.

All variants are equally lethal to the integrity of your data.

Comment: No-no, the card now a valuable part of the test bench, responsible for producing  garbage reads : ) Funnily, it wasn't written at all; was even write-protected with https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool